# Writing chinese characters to csv/txt file using R

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I have a data frame which is below

```
number          Name
13122072743 \u4e1c\u4e0a\u6d77\u52a0\u6cb9\u5c0f\u5f20
02158822171 \u4e1c\u65b9\u533b\u9662\u7279\u8bca
13681719939 \u502a\u6c11/M
13681719939 \u502a\u6c11/M
```

Name column is in Chinese, I am using

```
stri_unescape_unicode(gsub("\\U","\\u",new_data$Name, fixed=TRUE))
```

from "string" package which is converting name to chinese. But when I am writing it to txt/csv it is not writing in Chinese.

output I am getting in R is

```
"东上海加油小张" "东方医院特诊"   "倪民/M"         "倪民/M"
```

Can someone suggest a way to write this output to csv/txt file.

Comment: I edited your code to fix formating and didn't change your text, but I assume you meant `stringi` and not `string` package, right?

Comment: yes , I meant  "stringi"

Comment: One solution is to use `writeLines()` `writeLines(text = x, con = "test.txt", useBytes = T)`

Comment: Vlo gives the right answer, `writeLines` works! (instead of using `write.csv`)